# Is there something similar to RealBasic or LiveCode, but that uses Javascript/HTML as a language?

Tags: javascript, macos, user-interface, realbasic, livecode

I'm a programming "enthusiast", not a pro, and I'm looking for an easy graphical programming environment (for desktop, on the Mac and iOS) similar to RealBasic or RunRev Livecode.

However, because my available time is limited, I'd rather spend it into something that uses a more ubiquitous language like Javascript/Html5 (so I can transfer this knowledge into other areas like web programming) rather than an idiosyncratic language like the one used by Livecode or RealBasic (which cannot be used outside of that specific programming environment).

I've looked into Appcelerator Titanium (which uses Javascript/HTML/CSS), but it doesn't seem to have an easy GUI development interface.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Newer versions of RealBasic can deploy [web apps](http://www.realsoftware.com/web/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what i actually meant was that i'd rather not learn RealBasic ( as a language ), i would prefer to learn Javascript/HTML5 but use an environment that has a GUI builder ( like in RealBasic and Livecode )

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry for misunderstanding :)

Comment: But RealBasic is really easy... it's just like VB, which is also really easy. I doubt it will take you more than an hour to learn it. Also, what you learn in realbasic can be applied to web apps, and VB.NET can be used for ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

Wakanda is likely the closest I've seen as well.

My experience on a Mac is that it isn't terribly stable.  Not sure if that is just my env or if it's because it's still relatively new.  I like, and am very impressed with what they are doing, but just not sure I can trust it yet for production level stuff.

Realsoftware has an awful lot of perks.  I'm still exploring it but looks like it maybe what I'll use. It would be an easy decision if it was JS/HTML5!  It's all compiled and server side tho - as I understand it.

EDIT: 
Have a good look at Wakanda's NoSQL data capabilities. They are nothing short of amazing and very well thought out.  Four types, storage, calculated, relational and alias.  There's a good overview YouTube vid at https://vimeo.com/31837379

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the new Javascript Stack : Wakanda